# How to stub an users_controller | authlogic, rspec2, rails3, factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, authlogic, factory-bot

**My users_controller.rb**

```
# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
  @user = current_user
  #@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**my sweet looking users_controller_spec.rb ( notice all my commented out attempts )**

```
describe "Authenticated examples" do
  before(:each) do
    activate_authlogic
    UserSession.create Factory.build(:valid_user)
  end

describe "GET edit" do
  it "assigns the requested user as @user" do
    @user = Factory.create(:valid_user)
    assigns(:user).should be(Factory.build(:valid_user))
  end
end
```

**user.rb - factories**

```
Factory.define :valid_user, :class => User do |u|
  u.username "Trippy"
  u.password "password"
  u.password_confirmation "password"
  u.email "elephant@gmail.com"
  u.single_access_token "k3cFzLIQnZ4MHRmJvJzg"
end
```

Basically I'm just trying to get this RSpec test to pass in the most appropriate way.

I need to be able to say very simply, that the `mock_user` is the `current_user` .

This test passes if  I use in my users_controller.rb the `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this applies to Rspec 2, but according to the Authlogic docs you need to put this in a `before` method, or in `spec_helper`:

```
include Authlogic::TestCase
activate_authlogic
```

And then you can create user sessions as you would outside of the test environment.

FWIW I gave up on mocking/stubbing in Authlogic examples, and do `@user = Factory.create(:user)`, who are then logged in with UserSession.create(@user).

**EDIT**

Here's an attempt using the example you provided. I think the issue you're having is that the object in `assigns` is not the same as the one you're matching on.

```
describe "Authenticated examples" do
  before(:each) do
    # assuming you put include Authlogic::TestCase in spec_helper
    activate_authlogic
    @user = Factory.create(:valid_user)
    UserSession.create(@user)
  end

describe "GET edit" do
  it "assigns the requested user as @user" do
   # add a MyModel.stub!(:find) here if the edit action needs it
   get :id => 1 # pass in an ID so the controller doesn't complain
   assigns(:user).should == @user
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the `include Authlogic::TestCase` in my spec_helper . The activate_authlogic in my before(:each) like above. I **am** trying to use Factory to make the user. And from one of my examples above, is very close to yours. I'm guessing that right now, my problem comes from a syntactical problem. Ha! Wish me luck ;)

Comment: Looking at the updated code, did you leave out the `get`? Also, it looks like the result of `Factory.build(:valid_user)` will be different after each call, unless you've got some sort of singleton pattern at work in the factory.

Comment: Thanks Zetetic for responding. I honestly havn't the slightest clue what I'm doing here. o much so that even if it did pass, it might not actually be testing anything. :D  . That said, is there anything you could say explicitly to allow it to pass? It's so far, the most common set up for authlogic and rspec based off of this site http://rails.anyware-technologies.com.br/2009/04/21/tdd-on-rails-4-rspec-authlogic-factory_girl-and-resource_controller/ .

Comment: I included the factory_girl model above. Been stuck on this one code refusing to workaround it for three days now. :D I suppose rspec, like rails, has a learning curve, that once you get past the small battles, everything becomes clear. Thanks Zetetic.

Comment: See my edited answer. Rspec does have a learning curve -- your first post with all the comments looked like something I did myself :).

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! Thanks so much Z! :D It worked! On to the next failure lol

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in rspec-rails (see https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/391) that breaks activate_authlogic when used in RSpec's global before hook.

Instead of

```
# spec_helper.rb

# In RSpec.configure
config.before :each, :type => :controller do
  activate_authlogic
  user = User.new(:login => "user", :password => "secret")
  UserSession.create(user)
end
```

you can define a helper

```
# spec_helper.rb

require 'authlogic/test_case'
module LoginHelper
  include Authlogic::TestCase

  def login_user
    activate_authlogic
    user = User.new(:login => "user", :password => "secret")
    UserSession.create(user)
  end
end
```

and reference it in a before block when needed

```
# <controller>_spec.rb

describe "GET 'edit' when logged in" do
  before do
    login_user
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get 'edit'
    response.should be_success
end
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can define a shared context.

Comment: Great answer. But you need to put `include LoginHelper` at the beginning of your test.

Answer (score 1):

All are on this page :

http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase

You need put some information :

```
 require "authlogic/test_case" # include at the top of test_helper.rb
  setup :activate_authlogic # run before tests are executed
  UserSession.create(users(:whomever)) # logs a user in
```

Inf this case you just need change your `users(:whomever)` by your `mock_user`

Comment: @hingara, updated my code above, but i seem to be having trouble with proper syntax..